# HART Protocol -- Universal Commands serial communication through modem

Tags: python-3.x, protocols, instrumentation, serial-communication, modem

I have a few questions which I thought you might be able to help with:

I have been trying to carry out further communication with a Slave Device (FUJI A2 V5) on Windows 10 PC connected with HART modem and using both Python and Matlab.

Command 0 In short addressing mode works fine:
I send `FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0280000082`  and receive --
`"FF"   "FF"    "FF"    "FF"    "FF"    "06"    "80"    "00"    "0E"    "00"    "00"    "FE"    "15"    "02"    "05"    "05"    "03"    "0F"    "10"    "00"    "0D"    "91"    "43"    "A2"`
From the response, the slave uses HART version 5.

I then use the long address `["15"  "02" "0D"   "91"    "43"]` from Command Zero to get the Primary Variable (PV) using Command 1 as follows:

I send `FFFFFFFFFF8295020D91430001CB` but then I don't receive anything at all...

Am I missing something?
Thanks for the help.
/John

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the command number and byte count locations reversed.
Try FFFFFFFFFF8295020D9143**0100**CB

If you still get nothing, send more leading FF's.